# Something is wrong with array unique

Tags: php, mysql

Im having problem. I just connected to db and selected column and added it to array but, when i try to use command array_unique i get error that it is tring. What am i doing wrong here, cant uderstand, because it is array. Here is my code, hope you will help me:

```
        <?php
        $array1 = array();
        $query1 = mysql_query("SELECT ticket_company FROM {$dbprefix}tickets");
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query1)) {
            $array1 = $row['ticket_company'];
            echo "$array1\n";
        }
        $array1 = array_unique($array1);
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($array1);
        echo "</pre>";
```

And here is what prints

```
echo "$array1\n"; 
this one:<br>

 25 25 25 25 25 25 25 0 0 0 1 0 0 25 25 0 0 25 0 25 0 25 1 0 0 0 0 0 29 
 0 0 25 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 25 0 0 25 0 25 0 25 0 0 0 0 25 0 25 25 0 0 1 25 0 
 0 36 0 25 0 0 0 25 0 25 25 0 0 25 0 0 24 0 0 0 0 0 0 24 0 0 25 0 25 1 
 42 42 0 1 1 7 0 0 0 <br>
```

And the error:

> Warning: array_unique() expects parameter 1 to be array, string given in

Comment: `$array1[] = $row['ticket_company']; var_dump($array1);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$array = $row['ticket_company'];
```

`$row['ticked_company']` is clearly a string, sql databases dont have array columns. Perhaps you mean to add to the array;

```
$array[] = $row['ticket_company']; //note square brackets
//or if you prefer the verbosity
array_push($array, $row['ticket_company']);
```